# What process is diffrent between Python Requests and Javascript Fetch under the hood?

Tags: python, node.js, http, get

I was attempting to do some webscraping using python and as a first step used the `Requests` library to get the HTML of my desired page using the following

```
URL = "REDACTED"
html_doc = requests.get(URL).content
print(html_doc)
```

This resulted in the `html_doc` showing the contents for a webpage which is displayed when a user does not have access.

Determined to get it to work I tried it with NodeJS and fetch for no reason other than its another method I'm familiar with to see if for some reason the results would differ.

```
fetch("REDACTED")
.then((res)=>res.text())
.then((body)=>{
    console.log(body)
})
```

Above in the Node example the fetch request returns with the proper content of the page that i am looking for

My question is, what between these 2 methods would cause different results. does `requests.get` not do just perform an http request to the specified URL? Is it because of different headers that are used in `requests.get` that I would need to specify? The code works fine and I'm okay with the outcome I'm just looking for clarity on why they would show different results

Thanks